# Decoding base64 string with atob raises error, even though it doesn't have any non-ASCII characters

Tags: javascript, node.js, base64, buffer

I'm having this Base64-encoded string: `const encodedString = 'eyJ1c2VybmFtZSI6Imxha2VzYXJlIiwib2F1dGhQcm92aWRlciI6ImdpdGh1YiIsIm9hdXRoSWQiOiI3NTc4NTU5IiwiYXZhdGFyVXJsIjoiaHR0cHM6Ly9hdmF0YXJzLmdpdGh1YnVzZXJjb250ZW50LmNvbS91Lzc1Nzg1NTk_dj0zIiwiaWF0IjoxNDg1ODAxODI3fQ';` (**'{"username":"lakesare","oauthProvider":"github","oauthId":"7578559","avatarUrl":"https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/7578559?v=3","iat":1485801827}'**)

Decoding it in node works:

```
Buffer.from(encodedString, 'base64').toString();
```

Decoding it in browser doesn't (**Failed to execute 'atob' on 'Window': The string to be decoded is not correctly encoded.**):

```
atob(encodedString);
```

Comment: well, the `_` is wrong for a start - it should be a `/`

Comment: @JaromandaX, yep, I saw the `btoa` returning the `/`-ed string. In my case the base64-encoded string was generated by `jwt.sign()` function.
if you have an idea on why `jwt.sign` and `btoa` encode strings differently - please, comment.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using the `buffer` package (https://github.com/feross/buffer, `npm install --save buffer`):

```
import { Buffer } from 'buffer/';
Buffer.from(encodedString, 'base64').toString()
```

returns a properly decoded string.